# The interpretation of the economic significance in level-log and log-level models

Tags: regression-coefficients, logarithm

I have the following two models. The first is a level-log model, and the second is a log-level model. These models are two separate regressions and are estimated independently.

[image]

Assume that α=0.036 and β=0.549. Based on these values, I want to calculate the economic significance of the effects of my independent variables as follows:

Change in the dependent variables in response to one standard deviation increase in the independent variables.

Suppose that after multiplying α and β with the respective standard deviations, the final values are equal to 0.020 and 0.120.

Will you please tell me how should I interpret these two number? in %?
How much change is observed in my dependent variable in levels if the independent variable in log increases by 0.020?

I know how to interpret coefficients in level-log model and log-level models but got a bit confused here.

Will you please share your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Interpretation of $\alpha$ : one percent change in $X_{it}$ is associated with $\alpha * \ln\left(\frac{101}{100}\right)$ change in $Y_{it}$.

Interpretation of $\beta$ : an increase of one-unit in the Height would result in $\left(e^\beta - 1\right)*100\%$ change in $Y_{it}$.

For more information, you can see this [document](https://www.cscu.cornell.edu/news/statnews/stnews83.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your message. I do not have problems with interpreting α and β. My question was about its economic significance. Would 0.020 and 0.120 have the same interpretation as α and β?

Comment: I suppose 0.02 is $\frac{\alpha}{sd_\alpha}$. If it's this then, the coefficient $\alpha$ will be significant if 0.02 is greater than $t_{(3),\alpha}$ a student statistic.

Comment: I think I could not convey my message in a clear way. My question is about economic significance. Not statistical significance.

Comment: 0.02 is α multiplied by its standard deviation. I assume that the independent variable increases by one standard deviation.

Comment: I don't know if I understand properly. if you are talking about economic significance, it doesn't depend of the values you obtain by it more depend on the litterature review

Comment: But if you suppose an increases of one standard deviation % of $X_{it}$ and you want to see the increase of $Y_{it}$, it is like I said in my first message, $Y_{it}$ will change by $\alpha * \ln\left(\frac{101}{100}\right)$

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts. If we suppose there is a one standard deviation increase in X, then would not Y change by 0.020 * ln(101/100) instead of α * ln (101/100). This is exactly my question.

Comment: Ok, now, I understand. No, the change in $Y_{it}$ should be $\alpha * \ln\left(\frac{1+sd\%}{1}\right)$ but you have to insure that the increase of $X_{it}$ is in terme of percentage.

Comment: I am glad that we understood each other at the end. Sorry if I was not clear enough. Thank you again.

Comment: I hope you now find your answer in my last message.